Relation between graph thickness and crossing number
An exercise in "Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied" (so this is not a graph theory book) suggests proving that for a graph $G$, its thickness $\theta(G)$ and crossing number $\nu(G)$ are related as $\theta(G) \leq 1 + \lceil\frac{\nu(G)}{8}\rceil$.
I'm not even sure how to approach this, except to contemplate this relation as that, intuitively, if we build the decomposition of $G$ into planar graphs by inductively adding edges, we need one more planar graph (hence thickness goes up) when it becomes possible to embed either $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ into one of the already-built supposed-to-be-planar graphs. "Best worst case" giving the tightest bound is the embedding of $K_{3,3}$ having one edge that intersects all 8 of the others, hence keeping that edge and moving all others to a separate shiny new planar graph carries away 8 crossings.
But I'm not sure whether that makes sense, and even if it does, how to make it rigorous enough.

The relevance of $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ is simply that any graph with at most $8$ edges is planar. Therefore, given a graph $G$, we can:

Pick a planar drawing of $G$ with $\nu(G)$ crossings.
Delete edges from this planar drawing that are involved in at least one crossing, until either there are no more crossings left, or we've deleted $8$ edges.
Let $H$ be the subgraph of $G$ consisting of the edges we deleted. Write $G-H$ for the subgraph which doesn't have the deleted edges.

There are two corner cases. If there were no crossings at all, then $\theta(G)=1$ and $\nu(G)=0$, and the inequality holds. If there were crossings, but we eliminated them all by deleting fewer than $8$ edges, then $\theta(G)=2$, since both $H$ and $G-H$ are planar, but $G$ itself is not; the inequality $\theta(G) \le 1 + \lceil \nu(G)/8\rceil$ still holds. These two corner cases will be the base case of an induction.
In all other cases, we have $\nu(G) \ge \nu(G-H) + 8$: our planar drawing of $G$ gives us a planar drawing of $G-H$ with at least $8$ fewer crossings. Also, $\theta(G) \le \theta(G-H) + 1$, because $H$ is planar: one way to decompose $G$ into planar graphs is to decompose $G-H$ into planar graphs, then include $H$ as the last planar graph on the list. If we assume that $\theta(G-H) \le 1 + \lceil \nu(G-H)/8\rceil$, then we can conclude that $\theta(G) \le 1 + \lceil \nu(G)/8\rceil$, because the left-hand side increases by at most $1$, and the right-hand side increases by at least $1$.
